# CALayer calling NSView

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, calayer

Is possible for CALayer to call it's host NSView on OS X? The layer in question is a sublayer. The view is layer backed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that CALayer supports the methods setValue:forKey: and valueForKey to add arbitrary key/value pairs to a layer.  You could use that to add a view property to your custom layer and then access the view in your layer's methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

The layer doesn't have a way of accessing the view it is backing up directly. There is no "view" property on the layer.

However, if the variable for the view is in the current scope then it can access the view via that variable, just like any other object can.